# Custom keyboard for iOS in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Can I develop custom keyboard in *Objective-C* or only with *Swift*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it in either :)  When you create the project, XCode will ask what language you want to program in.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an image showing @Choppin Broccoli's answer.

[image] I hope they never take this option away